# Parsing a google directions json

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

I am working with google directions Api...But I am facing problems for read the Json response...Does Someone know about this Api and can help me?
I need get all route points to draw my polyline...which datas is important to get for it? How can I receive and parse it?

This is a json as example

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-22.8895625,-47.0714089&destination=-22.892376,-47.027553&key=

my code that doesn't work...

```
 public static async Task<List<Model.Localizacao>> GetDirectionsAsync(Localizacao locUser, Localizacao locLoja)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                List<Model.Localizacao> lstLoc = new List<Model.Localizacao>();
                var json = await client.GetStringAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + locUser.latitude + "," + locUser.longitude + "&destination="+ locLoja.latitude+","+locLoja.longitude+"&key="+ GOOGLEMAPSKEY);

                // json = json.Substring(json.IndexOf('['));
                //  json = json.Substring(0, json.LastIndexOf(']') + 1);
                lstLoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Localizacao>>(json);
                return lstLoc;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I really need a help
I have searched and the results hasn't helped me yet
its a xamarin forms project
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to pull out part of the json, deserialize the whole thing and grab the data you need from the C# object graph.

You can use [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate a C# class structure.

I pasted in the json you linked to and it generated the following:

```
public class GeocodedWaypoint
{
    public string geocoder_status { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
}

public class Northeast
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Southwest
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Bounds
{
    public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
    public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
}

public class Distance
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Duration
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class EndLocation
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class StartLocation
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Distance2
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Duration2
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class EndLocation2
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Polyline
{
    public string points { get; set; }
}

public class StartLocation2
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Step
{
    public Distance2 distance { get; set; }
    public Duration2 duration { get; set; }
    public EndLocation2 end_location { get; set; }
    public string html_instructions { get; set; }
    public Polyline polyline { get; set; }
    public StartLocation2 start_location { get; set; }
    public string travel_mode { get; set; }
    public string maneuver { get; set; }
}

public class Leg
{
    public Distance distance { get; set; }
    public Duration duration { get; set; }
    public string end_address { get; set; }
    public EndLocation end_location { get; set; }
    public string start_address { get; set; }
    public StartLocation start_location { get; set; }
    public List<Step> steps { get; set; }
    public List<object> traffic_speed_entry { get; set; }
    public List<object> via_waypoint { get; set; }
}

public class OverviewPolyline
{
    public string points { get; set; }
}

public class Route
{
    public Bounds bounds { get; set; }
    public string copyrights { get; set; }
    public List<Leg> legs { get; set; }
    public OverviewPolyline overview_polyline { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public List<object> warnings { get; set; }
    public List<object> waypoint_order { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<GeocodedWaypoint> geocoded_waypoints { get; set; }
    public List<Route> routes { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```